# Find domain selector with php

Tags: php, linux

I am a beginner in programming and I am designing a web platform in php which scans domain names and returns DMARC, SPF and DKIM records. I managed to implement DMARC and SPF. here is the code:

```
<?php 
      $spf=shell_exec('nslookup -q=txt '.$domaine);
      $dmarc=shell_exec('nslookup -type=txt _dmarc.'.$domaine);
?>
```

I found a shell command that retrieves DKIM records for domain names. Here is the command:
`dig selector._domainkey.domain-name txt +short`
The problem with command is that you have to find the selector for each domain before using the command.
However, the selector is different from one domain to another. Example of using the command on the cisco domain:

`dig iport._domainkey.cisco.com txt +short`

The result of this code is:

> "v=DKIM1;
> p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCctxGhJnvNpdcQLJM6a/0otvdpzFIJuo73OYFuw6/8bXcf8/p5JG/iME1r9fUlrNZs3kMn9ZdPYvTyRbyZ0UyMrsM3ZN2JAIop3M7sitqHgp8pbORFgQyZxq+L23I2cELq+qwtbanjWJzEPpVvrvbuz9QL8CUtS+V5N5ldq8L/lwIDAQAB;"

I'm looking for a way to find the selector of any domain to find the DKIM record of that domain automatically.
I ask for help please.

Comment: My brief googling suggests the list of selectors isn't intended to be public. https://help.sendmarc.com/support/solutions/articles/44001891845-email-provider-commonly-used-dkim-selectors has a list of common ones

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. But I would still like to know if there is a way to get the DKIM of a domain without going through the selector.

Comment: I found a site that finds the dkim record without asking the user to enter the domain name.
I am developing such a platform.
here is the website : https://easydmarc.com/tools/domain-scanner?domain=google.com . Please could someone explain to me how one can find the dkim registration of a domain without knowing the selector?

Comment: I don't believe that site actually provides DKIM selectors. It certainly doesn't for google.com, the domain you mention in your link